# How to get 2 e-Signatures seperately in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

My document requires 2 e-signatures and while creating the envelope i have only 1st signer's information and 2nd signer's information is not available. May i know how to use the same envelope and call UpdateEnvelope to get the 2nd signer's signature?

By using Create Envelope for 2 times, i can get both signer's info. But if I want to use the UpdateEnvelope call i am facing an issue. Appreciate your info.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this:

1. You can add a [special recipient called agent](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#agent-recipient) that can assign other recipients later. This way you don't have to know the second signer ahead of time.
2. You can [pause the envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/pause-workflow/) and then your code can run and modify it. You will need to use what we call "Correct" to modify the envelope. The tricky thing is that the envelope will be complete after the first signer signed if there's no other signer. So you need to modify it before it's complete.

Comment: Thanks, i was going over the API, looks like Agent also needs email.  Say if i give some email, how the agent will add the Signer 2 information? i don't have any screen for Agent in my application. My application has one landing page there first i give Signer 1 information, it takes to Docusign page get Signer 1 signature and saves it to DB. Then when Signer 2 login he has to fill in his information to sign the same document signed by Signer1.

Comment: Agent will get an email, the link in the email will take them to a screen where they can add one or or more signers to the envelope...